# How to check checkbox by default?

Tags: phpword

i want to check checkbox by default, but i could not find how to do it, in the phpword documentation there is no mention about it, found one option using addFormField, but it does not work like checkbox.

Comment: can you provide code you have tried already? according to the samples it's `$textrun->addFormField('checkbox')->setDefault(true);`

Comment: I'm using ->addCheckBox('chkBox1', 'Checkbox 1'); but in the docs it does not have example how to check it by default - https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/develop/samples/Sample_22_CheckBox.php

I tried using ->addFormField('checkbox')->setDefault(true); but for me it does not generate checkbox in word document, there is just empty space.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using:

```
$table = $section->addTable();
$table->addRow();
$cell = $table->addCell(11000);
$textrun = $cell->addTextRun();
$textrun->addFormField('checkbox')->setValue('<w:sym w:font="Wingdings" w:char="F0FE"/>');
$textrun->addText(htmlspecialchars(' Checkbox 1 '));
```

->setDefault() not working, but this solution works fine!

Answer (score 1):

this way if you using PhpWord template **TemplateProcessor** ,
you can just pass this Code **XML** as value  to your parameter **${checkedBox}** in Template

```js
 use PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor;
 
  $templateProcessor = new TemplateProcessor('yourTemplate.docx');
   $checkedBox='<w:sym w:font="Wingdings" w:char="F0FE"/>';
   $unCheckedBox = '<w:sym w:font="Wingdings" w:char="F0A8"/>';
  $templateProcessor->setValue('checkBox',$checkedBox);
```

Answer (score 0):

use "jumpski answer"
if the code has undefined error, add this block code in PhpWord/Element/CheckBox.php

```
 public function setDefault($default = false)
        {
            $this->default = $default;
        }
```